# Bootstrap vertically align 2 spans within a single div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a left hand side navigation card using Bootstrap and Bootstrap icons. On the left shows the name of the page to navigate to, and the right shows an icon - I cannot figure out how to vertically align these items

Please see code below:

```
<b-list-group>
  <b-list-group-item active to="/home" class="align-items-center">
    <div>
      <span>Home</span>
      <span><b-icon-house class="float-right" /></span>
    </div>
  </b-list-group-item>
</b-list-group>
```

I am also using Vue-Bootstrap, though that shouldn't affect anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `display: flex` to get your align to work properly. You can use the `d-flex` utility class for this.
I'd also suggest to avoid using `float`, and instead use flexbox to push the icon to the right. You can to this using the utility class `ml-auto`.

```html
<b-list-group>
  <b-list-group-item active to="/home" class="d-flex align-items-center">
    Home
    <b-icon-house class="ml-auto" />
  </b-list-group-item>
</b-list-group>
```